# How to update my app to Paid version and not create a new app

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic4

I use Ionic 4 framework and have two apps one for free one for paid, they are almost identical in features, but the free version has ads, the paid one doesn't. And also I changed widget id from config.xml file.
When a user goes from the free version to paid, I don't want them to have two separate apps on their phones. I want the paid version to be on the same free one and also keep the data if it's possible (I use local storage). Is that possible and how I can do that ?

Comment: I would recommend just having two apps. If you use the same app for both free and paid, anyone with root permissions can crack your app a lot easier. Also, instead of using a config file, maybe perform the check in the advertisement code itself.

Comment: I checked in the advertisement code, I just changed widget id So that I can upload it on google play store. I want to have different apps, but I want to keep user data and not to lose it after update. Thanks

Comment: Have you considered storing the data in an online database?

Comment: No, in this case it is more convenient to keep the data locally. I have seen the apps that had free and paid versions and after update the paid version was installed on the free one, so it became one app and it was with local storage as well. I want to understand how I can realize it, as now when I want to upload my paid version it creates two different apps

Comment: Did you try to go through "In App Purchase" approach to help unlock "paid for" functionality? there are plugins for that. These are trickier to get start with, but would serve the use case naturally.

Comment: Have you tried giving them the same "package names" ?

Comment: Such as "com.abc.123"?

Comment: @SergeyRudenko , I didn't try "In App Purchase" I want to make it two versions free and paid, Thanks

Comment: @J03L, It will work if I set the same "package names" but I should make the paid version higher than free version. Also as I know the package name should be unique, so that it’s possible to publish in google play store, isn’t that right ?

Comment: I dont feel like that would be the case, otherwise you would get app spammers that would try to fill up all the package names probably, but let me check. EDIT: Nevermind, you are correct. They will not allow same package names to be uploaded.

Comment: Perhaps have the user download the paid app through the free app instead of directly through the play store and have the free app then delete itself after the paid app has installed? Not 100% sure if this is possible without root though.

Comment: Did you get a solution for this? If yes, please share.

Comment: @Devner I contacted google support and they told me there is no way to do it, so I will have two different apps. So I put 2 different apps: free and paid.

Comment: @WebDev What I learned in my research was that Google was encouraging In-App Billing. This means they are encouraging us to have only one app and then when the user makes payment, verify the payment and enable other options. I saw that lot of apps are already using In-App billing and their case is exactly similar to the issue that you and I are facing right now. So having 2 apps is not only going to take more time for development, but also increases the risk of introduction of additional bugs. It would be a nightmare to maintain two versions, especially if your app has lot of features.

Comment: @WebDev So I really think that having 2 apps is not an efficient option for any app developer. I feel that what you are asking is very much doable and I am also looking to solve the same. We just have to find out the correct guidelines to do so. If any subject matter expert throws light on the issue, that would be of great help.